# Error starting Tomcat context.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.Message:Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' def

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, thymeleaf, crud

I have this simple CRUD Spring HTTP Service (see [image: project structure]). I would like to achieve something like [image: dislpay in browser]. I made use of Thymeleaf and 2 html files: add-edit-employee.html and list-employees.html.

Initial data comes from an sql table: data.sql & schema.sql. When I run the project I get error:

**Log of the errors**

2

```
021-03-11 00:51:57.529  INFO 11424 --- [           main] s.M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication  : Starting M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication using Java 15.0.1 on DESKTOP-D8AKRR2 with PID 11424 (C:\Projects\Workspace IT Academy\M13SimpleSpringHTTPService\target\classes started by Joan in C:\Projects\Workspace IT Academy\M13SimpleSpringHTTPService)
2021-03-11 00:51:57.541  INFO 11424 --- [           main] s.M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-11 00:51:59.369  INFO 11424 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-11 00:51:59.491  INFO 11424 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 100 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-11 00:52:01.118  INFO 11424 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-03-11 00:52:01.152  INFO 11424 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-11 00:52:01.153  INFO 11424 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-11 00:52:01.400  INFO 11424 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-11 00:52:01.401  INFO 11424 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3717 ms
2021-03-11 00:52:01.675  INFO 11424 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-11 00:52:02.492  INFO 11424 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-11 00:52:02.551 ERROR 11424 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Projects/Workspace%20IT%20Academy/M13SimpleSpringHTTPService/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, LAST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, JOB_ROLE VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, SALARY DOUBLE(4,[*]2) NOT NULL )"; expected ")"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL ) [42001-200]
2021-03-11 00:52:02.613  INFO 11424 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-11 00:52:02.621  WARN 11424 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@15.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2021-03-11 00:52:02.625  WARN 11424 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@15.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1055)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@15.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
2021-03-11 00:52:02.631  WARN 11424 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-03-11 00:52:02.652  INFO 11424 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-11 00:52:02.692 ERROR 11424 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:576) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at simpleSpringHTTPService.M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication.main(M13SimpleSpringHttpServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Projects/Workspace%20IT%20Academy/M13SimpleSpringHTTPService/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, LAST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, JOB_ROLE VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, SALARY DOUBLE(4,[*]2) NOT NULL )"; expected ")"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL ) [42001-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:259) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:233) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource  

..// A lot more lines /////..

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:243) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:1053) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:4995) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:6131) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:5697) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseTableColumnDefinition(Parser.java:8442) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:8379) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6276) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:903) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:819) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

**Pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>simpleSpringHTTPService</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleSpringHTTPService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>M13SimpleSpringHTTPService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:h2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

**EmployeeEntity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_EMPLOYEES")
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    -+fields        
    -getters/setters + toString + Inner Class with Enum...
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO 
    TBL_EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, job_role, salary) 
VALUES
    ('Joan', 'Coll', 'Employee', '1200.0'),
    ('Pep', 'Guardiola', 'Coach', '1400.0'),
    ('Leo', 'Messi', 'Manager', '1600.0'),
    ('Ronald', 'Koeman', 'Coach', '1400.0'),
    ('Joan', 'Laporta', 'Boss', '2000.0'),
    ('Risto', 'Shtoickov', 'Employee', '1200.0');
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_EMPLOYEES;
 
CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL
);

/**
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBL_EMPLOYEES (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL
);
**/
```

If I actually run it with property: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:C:/Projects/Workspace IT Academy/M13 Simple Spring HTTP Service/H2DB, instead of jdbc:h2:mem:h2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 it will start the app until I try to connect to http://localhost:8080/, then it breaks, and gives me a similar error, telling me that the table does not exist. Ideally, I would like to run it with datasource jdbc:h2:mem:h2db.

I have tried IntelliJ and SpringToolSuit and they give the exact same error. I have seen quite a few other threads about this, but I have not identified the error yet. Could it be that my Jar's are corrupted? Is it a matter of versions? I have checked and rechecked dependencies, properties..tryed adding dev-tools, and spring-boot-starter-tomcat...but it gives me also errors...There must be something I am missing. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace it is evident that, wehen springboot is starting up , it is trying to execute the schema.sql to create the tables that are necessary for the application and failing due to the syntax error :

```
    ot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL 
[file:/C:/Projects/Workspace%20IT%20Academy/M13SimpleSpringHTTPService/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, salary DOUBLE(4,2) NOT NULL );
 nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES ( ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, LAST_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, JOB_ROLE VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, SALARY DOUBLE(4,[*]2) NOT NULL )"; expected ")"; SQL statement:
```

I think the issue is the **DOUBLE datatype** that you provided for salary column in your create table query. As per the H2 documentation it does not take a scale parameter. So , the syntax that you provided in the create table query might be wrong which causes the issue. Try using a numeric instead to confirm.

Try(I haven't tried executing the query myself) :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_EMPLOYEES;
 
CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  job_role VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  salary DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
);
```

[H2 Doc.](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#double_type)

Comment: DOUBLE did not work, but:  salary DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NUL, did work. Thank you!